# How to track down sys_reboot function in Linux kernel for ARM architecture

Tags: linux-kernel, embedded, arm, beagleboneblack

We have Beaglebone Black based custom board, with Linux 4.4.
I wanted to track down the low level function corresponding to the `reboot()` system call.

I am able to see `sys_reboot()` in `include/uapi/asm-generic/unistd.h` however I am not able to get to definition of the `sys_reboot` function.

Where can I find the definition of `sys_reboot` in the kernel source?

Answer (score 2):

The `reboot` system call is defined in [`kernel/reboot.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/kernel/reboot.c) — look for `SYSCALL_DEFINE4(reboot`.

For ARM systems you’ll probably be interested in the ARM-specific support in 
[`arch/arm/kernel/reboot.c`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/arm/kernel/reboot.c), and perhaps in machine-specific support in one of the `arch/arm/mach-…` directories.